# Пропали апострофы после объединения двух CSV файлов

Tags: python, csv

Есть csv файл. Читаю из него методом `csv.DictReader(file_path)` строку

```
'id_product','reference','id_category_default','price','description_short','description','name_product'
3,00100,22,0,,,"Фляжка (береста, металл)"
```

Затем добавляю из другого csv файла

```
'src' 
"souvenires.ru/18462/flyazhka-beresta-metall.jpg"
```

и на выходе получаю файл, записанный методом `csv.DictWriter(file_path)`,
такого вида

```
'id_product','reference','id_category_default','price','description_short','description','name_product','src' 
3,00100,22,0,,,"Фляжка (береста, металл) ",souvenires.ru/18462/flyazhka-beresta-metall.jpg
```

Внимание, вопрос: Почему у наименования остались " ", а у ссылки пропали?

Comment: Точно не уверен, но, возможно, потому что они там просто не нужны? Апостроф — служебный символ в csv, который используется, чтобы экранировать какой-то другой технический символ. Во «Фляжке» есть запятая, поэтому апострофы там остались. В ссылке никаких спецсимволов нет, и питон убрал апострофы за ненадобностью *(это если апострофом вы называете двойную `"` кавычку)*

Comment: @andreymal возможно то тогда не лочгично как быть если мне неоюходимо именно с двойными кавычками держать ссылки в списке, или мне их добовлять при записи в CSV

Comment: Нужно было в изначальном файле обернуть строку с двойными кавычками в двойные кавычки и экранировать двойные кавычки двойными кавычками, вот так: `"""souvenires.ru/18462/flyazhka-beresta-metall.jpg"""` :D Крайние кавычки обозначают границы этой строки, а `""` внутри обозначают одну кавычку, и все нормальные приложения прочитают эту строку как `"souvenires.ru/18462/flyazhka-beresta-metall.jpg"` (можете в MS Excel проверить)

Comment: С другой стороны у вас в качестве спецсимвола может выступать не `"`, а `'` — тогда, возможно, ответ MaxU будет полезнее для вас (однако это уже не будет являться «классическим» csv)

Comment: @Drakonoved  Вы читаете комментарий когда принимаете правку?

Answer (score 1):

Для квотирования одиночными кавычками вместо двойных (по умолчанию) используйте [`csv.writer(..., quotechar="'", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer) при записи CSV.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ но немного не то, я впринципе понял суть проблемы, человек хочет на выходи видеть, то что довольнотаки проблемно получить, он хочет чтобы заголовки полей были в одиночных кавычках ' ', цифры без кавычек, а описание и ссылка в двойных кавычках " ", а как меня учили либо ' ' либо все " " вот в этом и геморой, почемуто описание на выходе в двойных кавычках а вот ссылка без ,но если попытатьсь добавить при записе кавычки тупо обновив по ключу с добавление кавычек '\"' + url + '\"' то в файлу появляються аж три двойных кавычки """url"""

Comment: @MadInc это уже, видимо, будет никакой не csv, а какой-то свой нестандартный велосипед, поэтому в таком собирайте нужные строки самостоятельно без использования модуля csv

Comment: дык и я думаю что бред нестандартизированный получиться, придеться выгибать заказчика всем спасибо

Comment: @MadInc Вы можете поправить вопрос, чтобы на него можно было бы дать однозначный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Впринципе использование и ' ' и " " и без кавычек в одном CSV - неформат, поэтому буду приводить к единой логике либо ' ' либо " "